# Firebase Delete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one listview and adapter ImageButton for delete data, but I don't know how to delete data by setOnClick. I need to click ImageButton and delete data. I have data type room not null.

```
    public class OrgManageRoom extends AppCompatActivity {

            private ListView listView;
            private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
            private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
        public ArrayList<String> arr;
        public ArrayAdapter adapter;

        private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_org_manage_room);

    //        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    //        listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    //        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_rooms);
    //        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            createAdapter();


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(OrgManageRoom.this,OrgAddUser.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


        }

        private void createAdapter() {
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllRoom");

            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                    while (i.hasNext()){

                        set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());

                    }

                    list_of_rooms.clear();
                    list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

    //                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }


        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                context = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list_of_rooms.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deleteroom, null);
                }

                // ColImgID
                TextView txtPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgDesc);
                txtPosition.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                txtPosition.setText(list_of_rooms.get(position));

                ImageButton cmdShared = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCmdShared);
                cmdShared.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(OrgManageRoom.this, "test" + list_of_rooms.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

                return convertView;

            }

        }
    }
```

Sorry, I edit all code and I make project chat firebase and show listview listroom for add user and delete user and manageroom. It deletes room edit nameroom. Same I need to click imagebutton for delete listroom.